# workaround for prepending to a LinkedHashMap in Scala?

Tags: scala, immutability, linkedhashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap which I've been using in a typical way: adding new key-value 
pairs to the end, and accessing them in order of insertion. However, now I have a 
special case where I need to add  pairs to the "head" of the map. I think there's 
some functionality inside the LinkedHashMap source for doing this, but it has private 
accessibility.

I have a solution where I create a new map, add the pair, then add all the old mappings.
In Java syntax:

```
newMap.put(newKey, newValue) 
newMap.putAll(this.map)
this.map = newMap
```

It works. But the problem here is that I then need to make my main data structure 
(this.map) a var rather than a val.

Can anyone think of a nicer solution? Note that I definitely need the fast lookup 
functionality provided by a Map collection. The performance of a prepending is not 
such a big deal.

More generally, as a Scala developer how hard would you fight to avoid a var
in a case like this, assuming there's no foreseeable need for concurrency? 
Would you create your own version of LinkedHashMap? Looks like a hassle frankly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work but is not especially nice either:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap

def prepend[K,V](map: LinkedHashMap[K,V], kv: (K, V)) = {
  val copy = map.toMap
  map.clear
  map += kv
  map ++= copy
}

val map = LinkedHashMap('b -> 2)
prepend(map, 'a -> 1)
map == LinkedHashMap('a -> 1, 'b -> 2)
```

Comment: This is a sleight of hand that enabled me to keep my core data structure as a val rather than a var. I went one further, and made an ad-hoc extension of LinkedHashMap (adding prepend()) using the "implicit def" feature of Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the code of [LinkedHashMap](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedHashMap.scala)? The class has a field `firstEntry`, and just by taking a quick peek at `updateLinkedEntries`, it should be relatively easy to create a subclass of `LinkedHashMap` which only adds a new method `prepend` and `updateLinkedEntriesPrepend` resulting in the behavior you need, e.g. (not tested):

```
private def updateLinkedEntriesPrepend(e: Entry) {
    if (firstEntry == null) { firstEntry = e; lastEntry = e }
    else {
        val oldFirstEntry = firstEntry
        firstEntry = e
        firstEntry.later = oldFirstEntry
        oldFirstEntry.earlier = e
    }
}
```

---

Here is a sample implementation I threw together real quick (that is, not thoroughly tested!):

```
class MyLinkedHashMap[A, B] extends LinkedHashMap[A,B] {

  def prepend(key: A, value: B): Option[B] = {
    val e = findEntry(key)
    if (e == null) {
      val e = new Entry(key, value)
      addEntry(e)
      updateLinkedEntriesPrepend(e)
      None
    } else {
      // The key already exists, so we might as well call LinkedHashMap#put
      put(key, value)
    }
  }

  private def updateLinkedEntriesPrepend(e: Entry) {
    if (firstEntry == null) { firstEntry = e; lastEntry = e }
    else {
      val oldFirstEntry = firstEntry
      firstEntry = e

      firstEntry.later = oldFirstEntry
      oldFirstEntry.earlier = firstEntry
    }
  }

}
```

Tested like this:

```
object Main {

 def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val x = new MyLinkedHashMap[String, Int]();

    x.prepend("foo", 5)
    x.prepend("bar", 6)
    x.prepend("olol", 12)

    x.foreach(x => println("x:" + x._1 + " y: " + x._2  ));
  }

}
```

Which, on Scala 2.9.0 (yeah, need to update) results in

```
x:olol y: 12
x:bar y: 6
x:foo y: 5
```

---

A quick benchmark shows order of magnitude in performance difference between the extended built-in class and the "map rewrite" approach (I used the code from Debilski's answer in "ExternalMethod" and mine in "BuiltIn"):

```
 benchmark length        us linear runtime
ExternalMethod     10   1218.44 =
ExternalMethod    100   1250.28 =
ExternalMethod   1000  19453.59 =
ExternalMethod  10000 349297.25 ==============================
       BuiltIn     10      3.10 =
       BuiltIn    100      2.48 =
       BuiltIn   1000      2.38 =
       BuiltIn  10000      3.28 =
```

The benchmark code:

```
  def timeExternalMethod(reps: Int) = {
    var r = reps
    while(r > 0) {
      for(i <- 1 to 100) prepend(map, (i, i))
      r -= 1
    }
  }

  def timeBuiltIn(reps: Int) = {
    var r = reps
    while(r > 0) {
      for(i <- 1 to 100) map.prepend(i, i)
      r -= 1
    }
  }
```

Using a [scala benchmarking template](https://github.com/sirthias/scala-benchmarking-template).

Comment: This would work but I wanted to avoid having to extend built-in classes and maintain such new types. On the other hand, a quick local extension using "implicit def" (see comment to previous answer) seems more palatable.

Comment: While I understand your desire to keep it simple, I disagree that using implicits is actually simpler than extending LinkedHashMap. If the feature you need (that is, prepend in LinkedHashMap) is properly implemented, it might even get accepted into the standard library if it was submitted. However my main concern when always rewriting the entire map would be performance, as shown in the edit of my answer.